# Generating random word from database except ID field

Tags: android, sqlite, random

I made an application that generates random word from database. But there is a problem like that:
I insert some rows into the database and ID field is AUTOINCREMENT. I get a random word from database. But, when I delete a record and I insert the new one, as you know, the ID is skipping the old one.
So, when I try to get a random word, it may make an error occured. How can I solve this problem?
Thank you for your responds...

```
public void kelimeUret() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = kelimeler.getReadableDatabase();

    rastgele = new Random();

    Cursor kayit = db.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM kelimeler", null);

    kayit.moveToFirst();

    int max = Integer.parseInt(kayit.getString(0));
    int min = 1;

    int rastgeleKayit = rastgele.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

    Cursor kayit2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT ingilizce FROM kelimeler WHERE id=" + rastgeleKayit, null);

    kayit2.moveToFirst();
    String sonuc = kayit2.getString(0);

    olusturulanKelime = sonuc;

    kelime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kelime);
    kelime.setText(sonuc);

}
```

My code is here. Actually there is no problem. It works. But when random generates an ID that has been removed from database before, it gives error. I thought that I should generate an ordered numbers for records, but I couldn't find the way to do that. I want to do it in another way. (Not on ID)

Comment: please post your code and the error message

Comment: please edit your question. the code will be better readable for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your easiest bet is probably to drop the AUTOINCREMENT if you can, and instead handle giving an ID by yourself. 
Just query for the highest current ID and increment it yourself.

Comment: I should change the ID field to normal integer and when I'm inserting rows to the database I should get the last ID and increase it for the new row. Right?

Comment: Yes, thats what i described :P

Comment: Yes.. But I had another error! :( For example there are 3 rows in database. I delete the second one. Then, when I want to add new, how will I fill the second ID?

Comment: halilkaya, 
I think that when you think about it, you'll find the same answer as anyone can give you here but you're looking for some magical way: there isn't one.
You'll simply have to manually handle this problem. You can do this either with re-ordering your IDs every time or just building a little re-try logic in your random chooser, if he hits a null then keep trying until he found something. 
probably the latest would be your easiest.